# How to create a link that has a textbox "auto-filled"?

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

How do I create a link that when the user clicks, it will bring him to the Google page as shown below (with the **To** field completed):

[image]

Right now, what I've managed is to simply link him to https://mail.google.com/mail/#compose and this is what he will see:

[image]

Similarly, is there a way to achieve this on hotmail as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&tf=1&to=someone@gmail.com&fs=1
```

This shows the composition screen. To get the whole gmail interface, remove `&tf=1`.

If you also want to preset a subject, just add `&su=YourSubject` to the query string

Comment: cool =D do you have a solution for hotmail as well? btw how did you know that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about hotmail. And I knew the answer because I had a similar requirement myself not long ago.

Comment: I mean how did you get that information? the view source didn't give any clues did it?

Answer (score 0):

The data is sended by POST, I think. Try to trace the HTTP Header when clicking on the link that redirects to the already filled page, with the Firefox Addon "Live HTTP Headers" for example. If the third line starts with POST, look at the last line before "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", this is the sended POST data. You will probably find the auto filled mail adress there. If so, you can do a javascript POST request to the given URL: http://www.bennyn.de/programmierung/javascript/http-post-request-mit-javascript.html, or you can use a framework like jQuery.

Comment: "Try to trace the HTTP Header when clicking on the link that redirects to the already filled page", problem is, there isn't an already filled page. I typed the @example.com myself in the first image

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question but if you are to request a person to send an email then it is best to use the mailto: in your links so that it uses the computers default mail service. I am unaware if this uses web-based mail but it will open up the computers default mailing program (And it stops you from having to account for every different email service).

And I tested Dennis's answer, and it does work for me. What do you mean by 'It ain't working', any error messages? anything that can help solve the issue?

Comment: Dennis answer wasn't working, it's working now it's cool. Btw do you use your default mailing program?

Comment: Yes I do, I use outlook as my default. There are also plugins for some browsers such as FireFox that can set Gmail or Hotmail as your default mailto: target.

Comment: I was under the impression that non-tech savvy users don't use outlook and have no idea how to set their gmail/hotmail/ymail as their default mailto:target